# Change column names of identity tables (Asp.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I would like to change column names of all identity tables. I have already changed the names of the table but I would like to change the column names as well.
This is what I have so far to change table names.

Please let me know how can I change column names. For example:

```
Id = lngUserID
Email = strUserEmail
EmailConfirmed = strUserEmailConfirmed
....
```

Also, if I change column names, do I have to do anything regarding primary and foreign keys?

```
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("tblUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("tblRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("tblUserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("tblUserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("tblUserRoles");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onModelCreating Class, do the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("strUserID");
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p =>p.Email).HasColumnName("strUserEmail");
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.EmailConfirmed).HasColumnName("strUserEmailConfirmed");
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the list of old properties and the corresponding new column name in the a dictionary like below.

```
IDictionary<string, string> UserTableColumns = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            {"Id",  "lngUserID"}, {"Email",  "strUserEmail"},{"EmailConfirmed", "strUserEmailConfirmed"}};

            foreach (var property in typeof(ApplicationUser).GetProperties())
            {
                if (UserTableColumns.ContainsKey(property.Name))
                {
                    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(property.Name).HasColumnName(property.Name);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Also this is giving me an error
dbModelBuilder does not contain the definition of 'Model'

Comment: This is added on the OnModelCreating method of your DB Context

Comment: Thank you. I am getting this error:
dbModelBuilder does not contain the definition of 'Model'

Comment: This does not work at all. There are errors in the code. What is typeof(User)

Comment: property.Name does not represent a property. It throws an error cannot convert from string to System.Linq

Comment: Try this for Id column of ApplicationUser and if it is fine, do the same for others. `builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("lngUserID");`